# Getting "NEXT VALUE FOR" for a SQL Server sequence using EF Core 3.1 - impossible?

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework-core, sequence, ef-core-3.1

I'm writing a new ASP.NET Core Web API, and one of my requirements is to be able to leverage EF Core 3.1 to grab the next value of a **sequence** defined in my SQL Server as the ID for a record I need to store.

I'm struggling to find a way to do this - in EF 6.x, I used a method directly on the `DbContext` descendant like this:

```
public int GetNextSequenceValue()
{
    var rawQuery = Database.SqlQuery<int>("SELECT NEXT VALUE FOR dbo.TestSequence;");
    var task = rawQuery.SingleAsync();
    int nextVal = task.Result;

    return nextVal;
}
```

and for EF Core up to 2.1, I would have been able to use `Database.ExecuteSqlCommand()` to run a SQL snippet and get back results. But it seems, in EF Core 3.x, I'm out of luck....

I know there are the `.FromSqlRaw()` and `.FromSqlInterpolated` methods on the `DbSet` - but since I only need to return the next value of a sequence (an `INT`), that's not going to fly. And I also know these methods also exist on the `context.Database` level which looks like it would be really close to what I had in EF 6.x - but here, those methods will **only** return the number of rows affected - I haven't found a way to send back the new value from the `SEQUENCE`.

Can it really be that in EF Core 3.x, I have to actually resort back to way-old ADO.NET code to fetch that value?? Is there **REALLY** no way to execute an arbitrary SQL snippet and get back some results from the context??

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you want to run an arbitrary TSQL batch and return a scalar value, you can do it like this:

```
var p = new SqlParameter("@result", System.Data.SqlDbType.Int);
p.Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Output;
context.Database.ExecuteSqlRaw("set @result = next value for some_seq", p);
var nextVal = (int)p.Value;
```

Comment: Hi when i tried this i got "Unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter' to type 'Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleParameter'." Can you please help me

Comment: If you have a question, ask a new question.  Both the types and SQL would be different for Oracle.

Comment: This is the only working code in .NET 7. Thanks.

Answer (score 13):

Looks like executing raw SQL is not priority for EF Core, so up to now (EF Core 3.1) it's providing publicly just few basic limited methods. `FromSql` requires entity type or [keyless entity type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/keyless-entity-types), and `ExecuteSqlRaw` / `ExecuteSqlInterpolated` are the "modern" bridge to ADO.NET `ExecuteNonQuery` which returns the affected rows.

The good thing is that EF Core is built on top of a public service architecture, so it can be used to add some missing functionalities. For instance, services can be used to build the so called [IRelationalCommand](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.storage.irelationalcommand?view=efcore-3.1), which has all the `DbCommand` execute methods, in particular `ExecuteScalar` needed for SQL in question.

Since EF Core model supports sequences, there is also a service for building the `IRelationalCommand` needed to retrieve the next value (used internally by HiLo value generators).

With that being said, following is a sample implementation of the custom method in question using the aforementioned concepts:

```cs
using System;
using System.Globalization;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Diagnostics;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update;

namespace Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore
{
    public static partial class CustomExtensions
    {
        public static long GetNextSequenceValue(this DbContext context, string name, string schema = null)
        {
            var sqlGenerator = context.GetService<IUpdateSqlGenerator>();
            var sql = sqlGenerator.GenerateNextSequenceValueOperation(name, schema ?? context.Model.GetDefaultSchema());
            var rawCommandBuilder = context.GetService<IRawSqlCommandBuilder>();
            var command = rawCommandBuilder.Build(sql);
            var connection = context.GetService<IRelationalConnection>();
            var logger = context.GetService<IDiagnosticsLogger<DbLoggerCategory.Database.Command>>();
            var parameters = new RelationalCommandParameterObject(connection, null, null, context, logger);
            var result = command.ExecuteScalar(parameters);
            return Convert.ToInt64(result, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Ivan - works, but seems quite a bit more complicated than David's solution.

Comment: Yeah, I know that you could use output `DbParameter`s. But my solution is db agnostic, and also the code starting from `var command = …` and ending with `result = …` can be used as base for creating `ExecuteScalar` equivalent helper for executing arbitrary single value returning SQL, that's why I posted this rather than the obvious (and SqlServer) bound solution. Cheers.

Comment: I ran into a problem when trying to use your code when I tried to specify the schema - my sequence is created as `CREATE SEQUENCE dbo.TestSequence` - but when I tried to pass `TestSequence` as `name` and `dbo` as `schema`, the `IModel.FindSequence` returned `null` - omitting the schema works..... any ideas?

Comment: It depends on your sequence fluent mapping, in particular whether you passed the `schema` to `HasSequence` or not. i.e. if you used `modelBuilder.HasSequence("TestSequence", "dbo");`, then pass `"dbo"`, otherwise (`modelBuilder.HasSequence("TestSequence");`) don't pass (or pass `null`) `schema`.

Comment: I created my database the "traditional" way - by executing SQL scripts - using `CREATE SEQUENCE dbo.TestSequence` - so I was expecting the schema to be there and be relevant ...

Comment: So you don't have fluent configuration (mapping) for your sequence (`HasSequence`)? Db First (scaffold)? May be it doesn't map sequences, actually I always used code first _ migrations where one need to add such mapping.

Comment: Actually the code doesn't need the sequence mapping (I've used it just because EFC generator was using it). The updated code will work when you pass "dbo" or if you don't pass it, but the (scaffolded) context contains `modelBuilder.HasDefaultSchema("dbo");`.

Answer (score 7):

In your fluent api configs you can create migration that set ID automatically to be next value from Sequence

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.HasSequence<int>("OrderNumbers");

    modelBuilder.Entity<Order>()
        .Property(o => o.OrderNo)
        .HasDefaultValueSql("NEXT VALUE FOR shared.OrderNumbers");
}
```

For creating sequence:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.HasSequence<int>("OrderNumbers", schema: "shared")
        .StartsAt(1000)
        .IncrementsBy(5);
}
```

Read more from here: https://www.talkingdotnet.com/use-sql-server-sequence-in-entity-framework-core-primary-key/

Comment: This will only work if your property is nullable, if it isn't for it will fallback to default value. 
https://github.com/dotnet/EntityFramework.Docs/issues/3852

So if you try to insert integer, it will send "0" as it's default value.

Answer (score 1):

For people suffering with oracle version of this problem, here's a solution:

```
var p = new OracleParameter("result", OracleDbType.Decimal, null, System.Data.ParameterDirection.Output);
Database.ExecuteSqlRaw($"BEGIN :result := my_seq.nextval; END;", p);
var nextVal = p.Value;
```

Comment: Thanku so much dude.i spent 6 hours finding solution for oracle.u saved my sleep.

Answer (score 0):

Ugly, but the best thing I could come up with:

```
var connection = repcontext.Database.GetDbConnection();
connection.Open();
using var cmd = connection.CreateCommand();
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT NEXT VALUE FOR AA.TransSeq;";
var obj = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
connection.Close();
seqnum = (int)obj;
```

Comment: it does not work when you have started a transaction

Answer (score -1):

This code should work in a variety of situations:

```
public static class DbSequence
{
    private const string sqlCode = "SELECT NEXT VALUE FOR {0}.{1};";

    public static T GetNextSeq<T>(this DbContext dbContext, string seqName)
    {
        var sqlCnn = dbContext.Database.GetDbConnection();
        bool cnnClosed = sqlCnn.State != ConnectionState.Open;
        if (cnnClosed) sqlCnn.Open();
        try
        {
            using (var sqlCmd = sqlCnn.CreateCommand())
            {
                sqlCmd.Transaction = dbContext.Database.CurrentTransaction?.GetDbTransaction();
                sqlCmd.CommandText = string.Format(sqlCode, "dbo", seqName);
                var result = sqlCmd.ExecuteScalar();
                if ((result == null) || (result == DBNull.Value)) throw new InvalidOperationException();
                return (T)result;
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            if (cnnClosed) sqlCnn.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

This code works when the connection is closed, opening it when needed and closing it after itself. It should also work when a transaction has been initiated. According to this source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-sequence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#general-remarks sequences run outside of transactions. Still, if it's available, I set up a transaction for the command. I also use generics and extension methods.

Comment: Doesn't solve the main problem that was solved in the accepted answer. This answer doesn't add anything essentially new.