# Unit test for SQL sequence

Tags: c#, unit-testing, entity-framework-core, xunit

Dears,

I use an external method to generate value from sequence and this like of code [Getting "NEXT VALUE FOR" for a SQL Server sequence using EF Core 3.1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60674700)

Now I'm writing a unit test case to get the next value from the sequence but I get this error

> Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.IUpdateSqlGenerator'. This is often because no database provider has been configured for this DbContext. A provider can be configured by overriding the 'DbContext.OnConfiguring' method or by using 'AddDbContext' on the application service provider. If 'AddDbContext' is used, then also ensure that your DbContext type accepts a DbContextOptions object in its constructor and passes it to the base constructor for DbContext.

how I fix this issue and thanks for your time

Comment: I don't know the exact issue but you might be missing the call to `UseSqlServer` method which set the SQL Server as the database provider.

Comment: I use "UseInMemoryDatabase" so I wait to mock this external method

Comment: I would recommend to write integration tests for database rather than unit tests. It might be possible that the in-memory database doesn't even support custom sequences. You can't expect the in-memory database to behave exactly the same as SQL Server

Comment: Thanks for your support,
Is there any way to mock this external method?

Comment: Which external method?

Comment: this method https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60644544/getting-next-value-for-for-a-sql-server-sequence-using-ef-core-3-1-impossibl/60674700#60674700

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236672/discussion-between-shady-youssery-and-navjot-singh).

Comment: Consider to compare odds that somebody brake this method vs time you spent on "fighting the framework" ;)

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you'll be able to do unit test with SQL server, because unit testing is about functionality of the methods in your code. And that is why we mock things like interfaces.

If you want to test the functionality in relation with any database providers you should try and write integration tests as @Navjot recommended.

Answer (score 1):

The InMemory provider is not a relational provider, if you want to test relational constructs use a real database engine.