# How to determine the next primary key from a database table for a generic entity using Entity Framework Core?

Tags: c#, generics, entity-framework-core, repository, primary-key

I have created the following generic repository that is the parent to all of my other repositories.

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using FlasherData.Repositories.Interfaces;

namespace Data.Repositories
{
    public abstract class GenericRepository<TEntity> : IGenericRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class
    {
        protected readonly DbContext _context;

        public GenericRepository(DbContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Finds an entity of TEntity type with the given primary key value.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="id"></param>
        /// <returns>The entity found or null.</returns>
        public virtual TEntity Get(int id)
        {
            try
            {
                return _context.Set<TEntity>().Find(id);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                throw new Exception($"Could not find entity: {e.Message}");
            }
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// Finds an entity of TEntity type with the given primary key value.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="id"></param>
        /// <returns>The entity found or null.</returns>
        public virtual async Task<TEntity> GetAsync(int id)
        {
            try
            {                
                return await _context.Set<TEntity>().FindAsync(id);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                throw new Exception($"Could not find entity: {e.Message}");
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Finds all entities of TEnitity type.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>A List<TEntity> of the entities found of TEntity type</returns>  
        public virtual IList<TEntity> GetAll()
        {
            try
            {
                return _context.Set<TEntity>().ToList();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                throw new Exception($"Could not find entities: {e.Message}");
            }
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// Asynchronously finds all entities of TEnitity type.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>A List<TEntity> of the entities found of TEntity type</returns>  
        public virtual async Task<IList<TEntity>> GetAllAsync()
        {
            try
            {                
                return await _context.Set<TEntity>().ToListAsync();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                throw new Exception($"Could not find entities: {e.Message}");
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Filters a sequence of values of TEntity type based on a predicate.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="predicate"></param>
        /// <returns>An IQueryable<TEntity> that contains elements of TEntity type from the input sequence that satisfy the condition specified by the predicate.</returns>   
        public virtual IEnumerable<TEntity> Where(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> predicate)
        {
            try
            {
                if (predicate == null)
                {
                    throw new ArgumentNullException($"{nameof(TEntity)} predicate must not be null");
                }
                return _context.Set<TEntity>().Where(predicate);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                throw new Exception($"Could not find entity: { e.Message}");
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Filters a value of TEntity type based on a predicate.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="predicate"></param>
        /// <returns>An entity of TEntity type from the input sequence that satisfy the condition specified by the predicate.</returns>   
        public virtual TEntity WhereSingleOrDefault(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> predicate)
        {
            if (predicate == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException($"{nameof(TEntity)} entity must not be null");
            }
            try
            {
                return _context.Set<TEntity>().SingleOrDefault(predicate);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                throw new Exception($"could not be find entity: {e.Message}");
            }
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// Asynchronously filters a value of TEntity type based on a predicate.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="predicate"></param>
        /// <returns>An entity of TEntity type from the input sequence that satisfy the condition specified by the predicate.</returns>   
        public virtual async Task<TEntity> WhereSingleOrDefaultAsync(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> predicate)
        {
            if (predicate == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException($"{nameof(TEntity)} entity must not be null");
            }
            try
            {
                return await _context.Set<TEntity>().SingleOrDefaultAsync(predicate);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                throw new Exception($"could not be find entity: {e.Message}");
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Determines if entity with the given primary key value exists.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="id"></param>
        /// <returns>A boolean; true if the entity exists or false if the entity does not exist. </returns>
        public virtual bool Exists(int id)
        {
            try
            {
                var response = _context.Set<TEntity>().Find(id);
                if (response != null)
                {
                    return true;
                }
                else
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                throw new Exception($"Could not find entity: {e.Message}");
            }
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// Asynchronously determines if entity with the given primary key value exists.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="id"></param>
        /// <returns>A boolean; true if the entity exists or false if the entity does not exist. </returns>
        public virtual async Task<bool> ExistsAsync(int id)
        {
            try
            {
                var response = await _context.Set<TEntity>().FindAsync(id);
                if (response != null)
                {
                    return true;
                }
                else
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                throw new Exception($"Could not find entity: {e.Message}");
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Adds an entity to the dbcontext.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="entity"></param>
        /// <returns>An integer that is the primary key of the added entity.</returns>
        public virtual int Add(TEntity entity)
        {
            try
            {
                if (entity == null)
                {
                    throw new ArgumentNullException($"{nameof(TEntity)} entity must not be null");
                }
                var result = _context.Set<TEntity>().Add(entity);
                int pk = GetPrimaryKey(entity);
                return pk;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                throw new Exception($"{nameof(TEntity)} could not be added: {e.Message}");
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Asynchronously adds an entity to the dbcontext.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="entity"></param>
        /// <returns>An integer that is the primary key of the added entity.</returns>
        public virtual async Task<int> AddAsync(TEntity entity)
        {
            try
            {
                if (entity == null)
                {
                    throw new ArgumentNullException($"{nameof(TEntity)} entity must not be null");
                }                                
                var result = await _context.Set<TEntity>().AddAsync(entity);
                int pk = GetPrimaryKey(entity);
                return pk;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                throw new Exception($"{nameof(TEntity)} could not be added: {e.Message}");
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Adds multiple entities to the dbcontext.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="entity"></param>
        /// <returns>A List<int> that are the primary keys of the added entities.</int></returns>
        public virtual IList<int> AddRange(IEnumerable<TEntity> entities)
        {
            try
            {
                List<int> pks = new List<int>();

                if (entities == null)
                {
                    throw new ArgumentNullException($"{nameof(TEntity)} entity must not be null");
                }
                _context.Set<TEntity>().AddRange(entities);
                foreach (TEntity e in entities)
                {
                    pks.Add(GetPrimaryKey(e));
                }
                return pks;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                throw new Exception($"{nameof(IEnumerable<TEntity>)} could not be added: {e.Message}");
            }
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// Asynchronously adds multiple entities to the dbcontext.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="entity"></param>
        /// <returns>A List<int> that are the primary keys of the added entities.</int></returns>
        public virtual async Task<IList<int>> AddRangeAsync(IEnumerable<TEntity> entities)
        {            
            try
            {
                List<int> pks = new List<int>();

                if (entities == null)
                {
                    throw new ArgumentNullException($"{nameof(TEntity)} entity must not be null");
                }
                await _context.Set<TEntity>().AddRangeAsync(entities);
                foreach (TEntity e in entities)
                {
                    pks.Add(GetPrimaryKey(e));
                }
                return pks;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                throw new Exception($"{nameof(IEnumerable<TEntity>)} could not be added: {e.Message}");
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Updates the existing given entity.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="entity"></param>
        /// <returns>An integer that is the primary key for the updated entity.</returns>
        public virtual int Update(TEntity entity)
        {
            if (entity == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException($"{nameof(TEntity)} entity must not be null");
            }

            try
            {
                _context.Update(entity);
                _context.SaveChanges();
                return GetPrimaryKey(entity);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                throw new Exception($"{nameof(TEntity)} could not be updated: {e.Message}");
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Deletes the given entity.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="entity"></param>
        public virtual void Remove(TEntity entity)
        {
            try
            {
                if (entity == null)
                {
                    throw new ArgumentNullException($"{nameof(TEntity)} entity must not be null");
                }
                _context.Set<TEntity>().Remove(entity);
                _context.SaveChanges();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                throw new Exception($"{nameof(TEntity)} could not be removed: {e.Message}");
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Deletes multilple given entities.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="entities"></param>
        public virtual void RemoveRange(IEnumerable<TEntity> entities)
        {
            try
            {
                if (entities == null)
                {
                    throw new ArgumentNullException($"{nameof(TEntity)} entity must not be null");
                }
                _context.Set<TEntity>().RemoveRange(entities);
                _context.SaveChanges();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                throw new Exception($"{nameof(IEnumerable<TEntity>)} could not be added: {e.Message}");
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Saves changes to dbcontext for an entity
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="entity"></param>
        /// <returns>An integer representing the number of entites changed during the save</returns>
        public virtual int SaveChanges(TEntity entity)
        {
            if (entity == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException($"{nameof(TEntity)} entity must not be null");
            }

            try
            {
                _context.Update(entity);
                return _context.SaveChanges(); 
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                throw new Exception($"{nameof(TEntity)} could not be updated: {e.Message}");
            }
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// Asynchronously saves changes to dbcontext for an entity
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="entity"></param>
        /// <returns>An integer representing the number of entites changed during the save</returns>
        public virtual async Task<int> SaveChangesAsync(TEntity entity)
        {
            if (entity == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException($"{nameof(TEntity)} entity must not be null");
            }

            try
            {
                _context.Update(entity);                
                int entitiesChanged = await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                return entitiesChanged;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                throw new Exception($"{nameof(TEntity)} could not be updated: {e.Message}");
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Finds the primary key of the given entity
        /// </summary>
        /// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
        /// <param name="entity"></param>
        /// <returns>An integer that is the primary key for the given entity.</returns>
        public virtual int GetPrimaryKey(TEntity entity)
        {
            var keyName = _context.Model.FindEntityType(typeof(TEntity)).FindPrimaryKey().Properties
                .Select(x => x.Name).Single();

            return (int)entity.GetType().GetProperty(keyName).GetValue(entity, null);
        }

    }
}
```

I need to add a generic function where I can extract the next primary key from the database using entity framework.

We have been asked to not use GUIDs to make queries easier for analysts and to use an ORM to stay database neutral (all queries, etc... done via ORM).

We may have to tell them that they must choose between these two requirements, but we hope to find a solution that meets these requirements and also does not have conflicts with concurrency.

This is what I have so far, but I have not been able to get the primary key value form the Key object.

```
public virtual int NextPrimaryKey()
{            
      int nextPrimaryKey = 0;
      var maxKey = _context.Model.FindEntityType(typeof(TEntity)).GetKeys().Max();
      //nextPrimarykey = ;
      return nextPrimaryKey;
}
```

Part of my problems is likely that I am new to generics so I do not know exactly what to look for or how to ask it.

Is there a better approach?
If this is a good approach, how to I extract the primary key value from the Key object?

Comment: And what value do you imagine all that code brings over simply using your DbContext directly?  Anyway if you want to pre-generate keys either use GUIDs or a SEQUENCE object in your RDBMS, eg https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60644544/getting-next-value-for-for-a-sql-server-sequence-using-ef-core-3-1-impossibl/60674947#60674947  The problem with what you have is that concurrent execution will produce duplicate key values.

Comment: We have been asked to not use GUIDs to make queries easier for analysts and to use an ORM to stay database neutral (all queries, etc... done via ORM). We may have to tell them that they must choose between these two requirements, but we hope to find a solution.

Comment: Propose that you have limited areas where you may need to provide different raw SQL solutions for different RDBMS platforms, and show how you can switch between them.  Or simply _don't pre-generate keys_.  Each RDBMS has a way to generate the keys on the back-end and each EF provider knows how to fetch generated keys during SaveChanges().

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft This is very good advice.  Our repository (see above) does capture and return the primary keys of new entries. Sometimes we are required to know the primary key before the changes are saved. Maybe the better solution here is working to find if it's possible to "delay" needing the primary key until after saving the new entries.

Answer (score 2):

Getting the primary key, generally, is not a good idea because it is an unpredictable action. At the time of returning the 'next' incremental value, it might already be in use because in the meantime your database was updated. If you'd like to know a key beforehand, you should probably use a GUID (either add it as an extra column, or use it as the primary key).

Comment: We have been asked to not use GUIDs to make queries easier for analysts and to use an ORM to stay database neutral (all queries, etc... done via ORM). We may have to tell them that they must choose between these two requirements, but we hope to find a solution.